# problems with \section in the appendix file in amsbook

Tags: sectioning

I have a single appendix and want to have sections A.1, A.2,..
I've begun each section with the command \section{title of section} and find that
A.1, A.2, A.3 work just fine with correct consecutive equation numbers (A.1), (A.2),..but the fourth section compiles as 1.4 rather than A.4 and with equation numbers (4.11), (4.12),..

Any ideas?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) without code it can be anything. Please provide a small but full document that show this behaviour. Might seem tedious, but this is a very valuable debugging tool, you'll often find the error your self when trying to make the most minimal document possible that also gives the problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem but I don't understand the solution: I set out to construct a minimal example that illustrates the problem but I ended up with a new master file containing all my original amsbook files (root, chapters, Appendix,...) and in which the problem no longer occurs. I can live with this but I'm curious to understand what happened.

Comment: as @daleif said in the comment to your question, without seeing the code that caused the problem, it's impossible to explain what happened.  if you saved your original master and chapter files, you could compare them to see what's different.  (that's what we'd have to do to debug this.)